# How to create an entire Eclipse installation package?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, bundle

Is it possible to create an Eclipse installation package, that contains a bunch of bundles and plugins? If so, how? (Like the ones that are already being offered by Eclipse.org and also from different vendors with their own projects)

The reason I am asking is, that I find it very time-consuming to install a bunch of software into development environment every time I need a clean installation of Eclipse (based on various reasons, corruptions etc.).

So I would like to install all the software I need at once, and save it somewhere else before working with it (as a backup) and if something goes wrong I can install the entire base installation again without being have to handle all the extra software in it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse is downloadable as a zip or tar file, so you can dezip it in a folder, add your favorites plugins (their will be store in the eclipse folder in plugins subfolder) and create a new archive with your modified environment (your eclipse folder).

I think It's the simple way to create a backup.

I hope it may help you,
Have a nice day

Comment: Well, among all the other things, this might be the easiest way to backup things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [Yoxos](http://eclipsesource.com/en/products/yoxos/), which allows you to create your own package of Eclipse and easily share it (including with yourself).

Comment: I was also wondering how distinct packages were distributed by the organisations. Somehow, I was finding it a little awkward that such groups would just upload their "folders" of Eclipse with their own projects as packages to developers. This seems of course more stable and professional.